# Symfony restfull json pagination

Tags: php, json, symfony, pagination, restful-architecture

I need create api method with pagination and I create action and service but I have response :

```
 {
 "self_page": "\\/app_dev.php\\/projects?count=10&page=1&sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC",
 "next_page": "\\/app_dev.php\\/projects?count=10&page=2",
 "prev_page": "\\/app_dev.php\\/projects?count=10&page=0",
 "first_page": "\\/app_dev.php\\/projects?count=10&page=1",
 "last_page": "\\/app_dev.php\\/projects?count=10&page=10",
 "projects": [
  {
```

and all data, I have 100 rows in DB then in header it displays correctly but why not work pagination I have to get 10 rows but I have all (100 projects) I create createQueryBuilder and if I debug in $queryBuilder I have right parameter (coutn 4 -> I have 4 project) but how this parameter use in pagination

```
  * RestView()
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="status", strict=true, requirements="[a-z]+", description="status of project", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="count", requirements="\d+", default="10", description="Count project at one page")
 * @QueryParam(name="page", requirements="\d+", default="1", description="Number of page to be shown")
 * @QueryParam(name="sort_by", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z]+", default="created", description="Sort by", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="sort_order", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z]+", default="DESC", description="Sort order", nullable=true)
 *
 * @param  ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @return View
 *
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException when not exist
 */
public function getProjectsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project');

        if (!$paramFetcher->get('status')) {
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('project')
            ->where('project.currentStatus != :identifier1','project.currentStatus != :identifier2')
            ->setParameter('identifier1', 'fail')
            ->setParameter('identifier2', 'rejected')
            ->orderBy('project.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
            ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
            ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    } else {
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('project')
            ->where('project.currentStatus = :identifier')
            ->setParameter('identifier', $paramFetcher->get('status'))
            ->orderBy('project.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
            ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
            ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }

    $projectAll = $repository->findAll();
    $paginator = $this->get('paginator');

    $pagination = $paginator->getPaginated(
        $paramFetcher->get('count'),
        $paramFetcher->get('page'),
        $paramFetcher->get('sort_by'),
        $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'),
        $projectAll
    );

    $projectResponse = new ProjectResponse();

    $projectResponse->setProjects($projectAll);
    $projectResponse->setSelfPage($pagination->getSelfPage());
    $projectResponse->setNextPage($pagination->getNextPage());
    $projectResponse->setPrevPage($pagination->getPrevPage());
    $projectResponse->setFirstPage($pagination->getFirstPage());
    $projectResponse->setLastPage($pagination->getLastPage());

    return $projectResponse;
}
```

and create pagination service:

```
class PaginatorService
{
public function __construct(Router $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function getPaginated(
   $count,
   $pages,
   $sortBy,
   $sortOrder,
   $projectAll
) {
    $this->count = $count;
    $this->pages = $pages;
    $this->sortBy = $sortBy;
    $this->sortOrder = $sortOrder;
    $this->maxPerPage = 10;
    $this->projectAll = count($projectAll);

    $dreamsResponse = new ProjectResponse();

    $dreamsResponse->setSelfPage($this->getSelfPage());
    $dreamsResponse->setNextPage($this->getNextPage());
    $dreamsResponse->setPrevPage($this->getPrevPage());
    $dreamsResponse->setFirstPage($this->getFirstPage());
    $dreamsResponse->setLastPage($this->getLastPage());

    return $dreamsResponse;
}

private function calculateNbPages()
{
    return (int) ceil($this->projectAll / (int) $this->count);
}

/**
 * Returns whether there is next page or not.
 *
 * @return Boolean
 */
private function hasNextPage()
{
    return (int) $this->pages < $this->getNbPages();
}

/**
 * Returns the number of pages.
 *
 * @return integer
 */
private function getNbPages()
{
    $nbPages = $this->calculateNbPages();

    if ($nbPages == 0) {
        return $this->minimumNbPages();
    }

    return $nbPages;
}

/**
 * Return minimum number pages
 *
 * @return int
 */
private function minimumNbPages()
{
    return 1;
}

private function getSelfPage()
{
    return $this->hasNextPage() ?
        $this->router->generate('get_projects', [
                'count' => $this->count,
                'page' => $this->pages,
                'sort_by' => $this->sortBy,
                'sort_order' => $this->sortOrder,
            ]
        ) :
        'false';
}

private function getNextPage()
{
    return $this->hasNextPage() ?
        $this->router->generate('get_projects', [
                'count' => $this->count,
                'page' => $this->pages + 1,
            ]
        ) :
        'false';
}

private function getPrevPage()
{
    return $this->hasNextPage() ?
        $this->router->generate('get_projects', [
                'count' => $this->count,
                'page' => $this->pages - 1,
            ]
        ) :
        'false';
}

private function getFirstPage()
{
    return $this->hasNextPage() ?
        $this->router->generate('get_projects', [
                'count' => $this->count,
                'page' => $this->minimumNbPages(),
            ]
        ) :
        'false';
}

private function getLastPage()
{
    return $this->hasNextPage() ?
        $this->router->generate('get_projects', [
                'count' => $this->count,
                'page' => $this->calculateNbPages(),
            ]
        ) :
        'false';
}
}
```

Comment: Because you fetching all projects? `$projectAll = $repository->findAll();`

Comment: in this case to make to output as much as in the count ? and begin next count

Comment: if I try get /projects.json?count=2&page=6&sort_by=createdAt&sort_order=ASC фтв still I getting all projects but I must get 2 project in page 6 - id 11 id 12. How do it right ?

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem I need to create queryBuilder and use sort_order sort_by and count and then I post queryBuilder in $projectResponse->setProjects($queryBuilder);

```
   public function getProjectsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project');

    if (!$paramFetcher->get('status')) {
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('project')
            ->where('project.currentStatus != :identifier1','project.currentStatus != :identifier2')
            ->setParameter('identifier1', 'fail')
            ->setParameter('identifier2', 'rejected')
            ->orderBy('project.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
            ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
            ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    } else {
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('project')
            ->where('project.currentStatus = :identifier')
            ->setParameter('identifier', $paramFetcher->get('status'))
            ->orderBy('project.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
            ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
            ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }

    $projectAll = $repository->findAll();

    $paginator = $this->get('paginator');

    $pagination = $paginator->getPaginated(
        $paramFetcher->get('count'),
        $paramFetcher->get('page'),
        $paramFetcher->get('sort_by'),
        $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'),
        $projectAll
    );

    $projectResponse = new ProjectResponse();

    $projectResponse->setProjects($queryBuilder);
    $projectResponse->setSelfPage($pagination->getSelfPage());
    $projectResponse->setNextPage($pagination->getNextPage());
    $projectResponse->setPrevPage($pagination->getPrevPage());
    $projectResponse->setFirstPage($pagination->getFirstPage());
    $projectResponse->setLastPage($pagination->getLastPage());

    return $projectResponse;
}
```